# Upgraded online from 20.04 to 22.04. Everything went fine, except Libreoffice not opening

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, libreoffice

Libreoffice document is not opening. All features are visible like menu. Neither any existing document is opening, nor a new document opens.. Uninstalled and re-installed the Libreoffice Writer. Still the same problem. How to solve it?

Command line:

```
ashoke@Dell-3470:~$ libreoffice 
ashoke@Dell-3470:~$
```

and then nothing

Comment: No "extra" output telling about problems, and not starting? Then try purge and reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is likely caused by a bad profile: that one does not get deleted when you delete/reinstall LO.

Start LO using the `--safe-mode` option and if that works it is indeed a profile problem. And to reset the user profile:

- Start LibreOffice using Safe Mode (Menu: Help -> Restart in Safe Mode and  Restart or use the session you started with the option `--safe-mode`)
- Archive your profile expanding Advanced (Advanced above Help button) and click Archive User Profile button if you want to.
- Reset to factory settings
- Reset entire user profile and Apply Changes
- Restart LO

Comment: In 'safe mode' it worked from 'Restore from backup' -. 'Restore user configuration to the last known user configuration.

Comment: But prior to that, I 'purged' 'LO and installed again from its PPA. Then also the problem remained same. Finally the above method worked.