# LibreOffice calc freezes when saving document

Tags: libreoffice, freeze

I am using LibreOffice 7.3.7.2 in Ubuntu 22.04. Things have been working fine for over a year now, but today I wanted to use LibreOffice Calc and found that it freezes when I want to save whatever change in whatever format, making it unusable. It happens only with new files, as soon as I click on "save" it freezes, no CPU usage. It is probably due to some update, because this was not happening before. LibreOffice Writer seems to work fine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you share more details on "save whatever change in whatever format" ?  Like what is the size of your data ? is it a small sheet, or does it have a lot of rows (and columns).  What format are your trying to save to ?  Why do you not update to a [newer](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download-libreoffice/) version? 7.4.7 is out, and stable, for some time now....

Comment: Start from command line using `libreoffice --calc`; put something in cell A1 on the _new_ spreadsheet displayed; close the LO window and save the sheet under a new named file. Does it hang? What do you see on the terminal window?

Comment: It does not seem to matter, it can be an empty sheet, a sheet with only one cell containing something, etc. I have tried the default format and csv. Will try the update.

Comment: If everything fails, try this (after reading): [How to Factory Reset LibreOffice](https://www.libreofficehelp.com/factory-reset-libreoffice/#:~:text=Steps%20to%20factory%20reset%20LibreOffice,-Make%20sure%20to&text=From%20the%20menu%2C%20click%20Help,option%20Reset%20to%20factory%20settings%20.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgraded online from 20.04 to 22.04. Everything went fine, except Libreoffice not opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427353/upgraded-online-from-20-04-to-22-04-everything-went-fine-except-libreoffice-no)